# How to check if my tomcat has started using Ansible

Tags: tomcat, ansible

I am writing a ansible script to automate my application deployment. I use `svcadm` commands to check tomcat status

enable tomcat - `svcadm enable tomcat`
disable tomcat - `svcadm disable tomcat`
check tomcat status - `svcs tomcat`

When i run the enable command after the deployment, tomcat immediatly goes into `online` mode and that's how I am checking if my tomcat is UP like this -

```
 - name: Verifying tomcat service to make sure it is in online state
   shell: "svcs tomcat"
   register: result
   until: result.stdout_lines.1.split().0 == "online"
   retries: 5
   delay: 30
```

BUT the thing is that does not necessary means the website is accessible. We verify that from the below logs -

```
09-Oct-2020 13:01:39.823 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /app/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/conf/Catalina/localhost/selfcare-enhanced-userinfo-mock.xml has finished in 31,590 ms
09-Oct-2020 13:01:41.003 INFO [localhost-startStop-4] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /app/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp1.xml has finished in 89,863 ms
09-Oct-2020 13:01:51.960 INFO [localhost-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /app/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp2.xml has finished in 52,709 ms
09-Oct-2020 13:01:51.994 INFO [localhost-startStop-5] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /app/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/webapps/psdv1
09-Oct-2020 13:02:36.948 INFO [localhost-startStop-5] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
09-Oct-2020 13:02:36.963 INFO [localhost-startStop-5] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /app/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/webapps/psdv1 has finished in 44,969 ms
09-Oct-2020 13:02:36.969 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Oct-2020 13:02:36.993 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
**09-Oct-2020 13:02:36.997 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 308347 ms**
```

Is there a way to check/monitor this log file and check for that last line and wait until this log occurs which tells us that the tomcat is up and running and website is accessible now and we terminate the script?

Comment: Would it not be better and cleaner to check whether service is available on the port it serves, than to parse log files and look for startup status?

Comment: @seshadri_c Hi, I have tried using ```wait_for``` but just because the port is open doesn't mean that the tomcat application is actually ready to service requests. So that's why I was trying to go for the logs so that I know that my tomcat is ready to serve the requests

Comment: Ok the same module can be used to check the file. I will post the solution.

Comment: @seshadri_c Ok I will try the below solution. So if i set the timeout for say 5 minutes, will it complete those 5 minutes or it will exist as soon as that log line appears in the log file?

Comment: As soon as the `search_regex` appears, the task will be complete. Otherwise it will wait for `timeout`. So if `Server startup` appears in 1 min, the task will be done, else wait.

Comment: @seshadri_c Ok perfect. I will try that. Just one more thing. The ```catalina.out``` could contain ```Server startup``` multiple times. How do i make sure it is picking up the latest one?

Comment: Your best bet would be to make sure `catalina.out` is empty before starting tomcat.

Comment: I updated the answer with another option, if emptying the file is not possible.

Comment: @seshadri_c Thanks so much for your detailed response. I was able to make it work using option 2 where I am tailing the Catalina logs. I will see if i can flush the logs out before my deployment starts and can use option 1. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can use the [Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/wait_for_module.html) `wait_for` for this purpose, and look for the term `Server startup` in the log file.

Example path of tomcat logs `/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out`:

```yml
# Empty contents of catalina.out before this task with some method

  - wait_for:
      path: /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
      search_regex: "Server startup"
      # set timeout if it usually takes more than 300 seconds to start
      timeout: 600
```

*Note that this requires the file to be empty to avoid matching an older* `Server startup`.

**Option 2:**

You can `tail` the logs and look for `Server startup` until it is found:

```yml
# Pause few seconds for logs to roll with initialization of Tomcat
  - pause:
      seconds: 30

# Tail the log 15 times with 20 second interval looking for Server startup (300 secs)
  - command: tail /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
    register: catalina_tail
    until: catalina_tail.stdout is search('Server startup')
    retries: 15
    delay: 20
```

You can set the `retries` and `delay` according to the time it usually takes for Tomcat to completely start.

Though in my experience with Tomcat, I haven't felt the need to preserve the `catalina.out` logs. So I would prefer **Option 1**.